# Infinite for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iteration, infinite

here's a for loop I'm using in my c++ program, it repeats infinitely and I cannot figure out why. (The loop is contained inside a method called "initialiseTaxis".

Here's the whole thing:

```
void initialiseTaxis (taxiDetails allTaxiDetails[14])//Initialise array of taxis
{int i = 0;
while (i < 15)
{   


    if (i = 0)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Downing";
    else if (i = 1)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Gilbert";
    else if (i = 2)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Downey";
    else if (i = 3)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Potter";
    else if (i = 4)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Elric";
    else if (i = 5)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Rockbell";
    else if (i = 6)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Tate";
    else if (i = 7)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Pratt";
    else if (i = 8)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Mansfield";
    else if (i = 9)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Hopps";
    else if (i = 10)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Willaker";
    else if (i = 11)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Singer";
    else if (i = 12)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "O'Connoly";
    else if (i = 13)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "McKay";
    else if (i = 14)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Spriggs";


    if (i == 13 || i == 1) // initialises wheelchair access (1 7 seat wheelchair, 1 5 seat wheelchair)
    allTaxiDetails[i].WheelChairAccessibleVehicle = true;
    else 
    allTaxiDetails[i].WheelChairAccessibleVehicle = false;


    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.bookingID = "0";
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.costOfCurrentFare = 0;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.overAllFareDetails = 0;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.taxiAvaliable = false;

    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.customerCoordinates = 0;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.customerName = "Null"; 
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.customerOnRoute= false;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.customerPhoneNumber = "00000000000";
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.dropOffCoordinates = 0;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.dropOffLocationName = "Null";
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.nameOfLocation = "Null";
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.seatingRequirement = 5;
    allTaxiDetails[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.currentCustomerDetails.wheelchairAccessYesOrNo = false;
    if (i != 13 || i!= 14) //Initialises number of seats with 2 seven seater cars
    {allTaxiDetails[i].numberOfSeats = 5;}
    else 
    {allTaxiDetails[i].numberOfSeats = 7;}

    allTaxiDetails[i].taxiID = (i + 1);
    allTaxiDetails[i].taxiAvaliable = true;
    allTaxiDetails[i].taxiContainsCustomerYesNo = false;
    allTaxiDetails[i].taxiCoordinates = 0;
    allTaxiDetails[i].taxiRank = "Train Station";
    cout << allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname;
    i++;
} //Initialise Taxis Method
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Sorry guys, I mean while loop.

Silly me. =)

Comment: Simple typo you are using `=` instead of `==`. Close reasons now include `simple typo`, vote to close.

Comment: by if (i = 0) you surely mean if (i == 0) in deed

Comment: Do as your instructor surely recommended and always compile with warnings enabled.

Comment: Now  [Yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) you will use.

Comment: -Wall is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

Your if statements look off, you should use `==`, not `=`.

e.g.

`if (i = 0)` should be `if (i == 0)`.

The array being passed in should also be of size 15, rather than 14. It's only the indices of the elements that start at 0.

Comment: No probs, gimme a tick if you're happy with it :-)

Comment: Change my mind.

The program now doesn't respond (n)...

Comment: This is concerning... It does what it's supposed to, then it crashes...

Comment: Definitely don't tick it then. My statement about the if's is correct though :-)

Comment: Try outputting the value of `i` on each iteration. In fact, have you checked that this is method that's causing the problem? I can't see anything wrong (although it is correct as someone has pointed out, that you can use a for-loop instead).

Comment: Dude can you help me please =( I have debbugged and checked my code, there's something in that code above that is causing the program to not respond.

Comment: Hold on, you're passing in an array of 14 elements. You should loop to `< 14`, as the value of `i` shouldn't go above 13, that's something to look at.

Comment: It outputs 0 through to 13

Comment: Change the the `while` to `while(i < 14)`. Also put a cout as the last line of the function and you'll be able to see if it returns.

Comment: ? wait, I need an array of 15 elements, so I should have an array size 14 shouldn't I? =S

Comment: Nope, an array of _size_ 15. It's the index of the array's elements that go from 0 up to 14 i.e. that's 15 numbers :-)

Comment: HOORAY!

Thank you sir, it was an overflow error, that didn't show up in the compiler  =S

Thank you =)

Comment: All working? If so, I'll edit my main post and kindly request the tick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your if() functions have only one =, should have ==, like:

```
if (i == 0)
```

Comment: And everyone already answered it :D

Answer (score 0):

You should have a compilation warning that you have not read that tells you you are doing assignments inside your if statements.

```
if( i = 0)
```

should be

```
if( i == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you technically have not written a "for" loop, but a while loop with a counter. It looks like you wanted it to iterate 15 times, you could replace these two lines:

int i = 0;
while (i < 15)

with this line:

for (int i=0; i<15; i++)

to create a true "for" loop. I can't quite see why your current setup wouldn't work, but since it is not, try my suggestion. and, of course, make sure the only time "i" is called is to be read as an index for the loop.

EDIT: the answers above are correct, you are using the "=" assignment operator when you want the "==" comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

It is funny that your program gets caught in an endless loop due to the fact that control variable i is always set to 1 inside the body of the loop independently of your last statement `i++;`

```
while (i < 15)
{   
    if (i = 0)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Downing";
    else if (i = 1)
        allTaxiDetails[i].taxiDriverSurname = "Gilbert";

    // other stiff

    i++;
} //Initialise Taxis Method
```

At first i is set to 0 in this statement

```
    if (i = 0)
```

but as the expression is equal to 0 compound statement of this if will be executed never.

Then i is set to 1 in the next statement

```
    else if (i = 1)
```

As the expression is not equal to 0 then the compound statement of this else-if will be executed. At the same time all other if statements will be ignored.

In the end of the loop you increase i. It becomes equal to 2. But in the next iteration due to the first statement if i is set to 0 and all repeats anew.:)